# How to use datetime.timedelta correctly. Getting wrong day value

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I'm using datetime.timedelta to get today's date - 5 days.
Today is 2020-5-22 and want to get 2020-5-17.

For this, I do:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
date = today - datetime.timedelta(days=5)
```

And instead of `2020-5-17` I get the result `2020-5-16`...

Has this something to do with timezones? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: in what timezone are you / what's the timezone setting of your operating system?

Comment: What do you see when you run "print(today) "?

Comment: you can just simply `print(today)` and `print(date)` to see the actual datetime

Comment: MrFuppes got it, it was my OS' setting... Thanks all, guys! I'm so dumb sometimes... Now I get the correct value.

Comment: If you work with datetime objects on a regular basis, it might make sense for you to make them timezone-aware. Ideally, in your code & database, you work with UTC - only if you output date&time e.g. to a user, apply the appropriate timezone so that it is "human-readable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my OS' settings as the user MrFuppes suggested.
I changed settings and now it works correctly.